# Taylor expansion of the acceleration between Sun and Moon

Tags: newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, approximations, celestial-mechanics, three-body-problem

We consider the tree body system (Sun, Earth, Moon) in the reference frame centered in the Earth rotating with angular velocity $\Omega$ around the Sun.

[image]

Let $\vec{y}=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ be the time dependent coordinates of the Moon.

Then the gravitational acceleration induced by the Sun is given by

[image]

I'm really struggling to understand how one gets from the first line to the second here. I suppose it is about Taylor expansion of the function $f(\vec{y})=\frac{1}{||R\vec{e_1}- \vec{y}||^3}$. Looking at the first term I guess we are expanding around $\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ but I have no idea where the second term comes from. If I'm not mistaken the gradient should be $\nabla \vec{f}=3\frac{R\vec{e_1}-\vec{y}}{||R\vec{e_1}-\vec{y}||^5}$.
I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor expansion is:

$$f_{Ti}=f_i\big|_{\vec y_0}+\left(\boldsymbol\nabla f_i\big|_{\vec y_0}\right)\,\cdot (\vec y-\vec y_0)+ \ldots$$

with

$$\boldsymbol \nabla=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} \\
   \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec y=\begin{bmatrix}
  y_1 \\
  y_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\qquad,\vec y_0=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$\vec f=\begin{bmatrix}
  f_1 \\
  f_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{R\,\vec e_1-\vec y}{\parallel R\,\vec e_1-\vec y\parallel^3}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {R-y_{{1}}}{ \left(  \left( R-y_{{1}}
 \right) ^{2}+{y_{{2}}}^{2} \right) ^{3/2}}}\\ -{
\frac {y_{{2}}}{ \left(  \left( R-y_{{1}} \right) ^{2}+{y_{{2}}}^{2}
 \right) ^{3/2}}}\end {array} \right] \quad
\Rightarrow\quad
 \vec f\big|_{\vec y_0}=\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{R^2} \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$f_{T1}=\frac{1}{R^2}+\frac{2\,y_1}{R^3}\\
f_{T2}=-\frac{y_2}{R^3}$$

and

$$\vec f_T=\begin{bmatrix}
  f_{T1} \\
  f_{T2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$